# On the graphs of a sequence of functions

Tags: sequences-and-series

For the sequence $\frac{x}{n}$, with $x\geq 0$, the graphs of these sequences are the lines through origin starting with $y=x$, $y=\frac{x}{2}$, $\cdots$, 
i.e. the sequence starts with the diagonal line in first quadrant (x-y plane), and slowly press the line towards $x$-axis without moving $0$.

Consider the following modification of above sequence:
$$f_n(x)=\frac{x}{n}e^{-x/n}, \hskip1cm x\geq 0.$$
**Question:** How the graphs of these sequences look like as compared to above?